# Can something be both a surface and an object for Glyph of Warding?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

There is a lot of speculation around the interpretation of this spell. Lots of people are differentiating between a 'surface' and an 'object' as mutually exclusive e.g. A table is a surface because it is specifically mentioned as an example in the spell as a surface. In doing this casting the spell on the table negates the 'object' rule of movement whereby the object cannot be moved more than 10' from its origin. My interpretation is that a table is both an object and a surface therefore must comply to both set of rules. Similarly a wall is a surface but if you cast it on a brick wall then remove the brick the glyph is inscribed upon, you've changed the nature of the 'surface' to an 'object' therefore the spell's rules change.

Is there a way I can fairly easily determine which way the spell works, or have I missed something?

Comment: Are you the DM asking on how to make a ruling, or a player wanting to use the spell?

Comment: You've added the [rules-as-written] tag, but you deliberately ask for details that aren't specified in the rules. What's the point?

Comment: I am both a DM and a player. The tag was supposed to be RAI not RAW. Although that tag doesn't seem to exist. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way I can fairly easily determine which way the spell works

No, there isn't.

If you are a player, ask your DM. If you're the DM, make a ruling. There always will be situations that aren't described in the rules, just because 5e PH is a (relatively) small book and spell descriptions aren't very detailed. As a DM, use common sense and your own understanding how magic works in your world.

See the related question about RAW interpretation of spells: [What is the source of the "spells do only what they say they do" rules interpretation principle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/)

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just checking that I hadn't missed some definition on surface and object that could have helped.

Comment: @RossConstable a "surface" isn't actually a term in 5e. An "object" is - [What is considered an object?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/)

Comment: Thanks enkryptor I have seen that thread before. It's just odd that WOTC would specifically differentiate between a surface and an object without applying a set of rules on how. Nevermind, as you have said it is up to DM ruling and as that's me I'll just work through it.

Comment: @RossConstable I've always read "surface" as something immovable. See also https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64943/

Answer (score 4):

If it can be moved, then it counts as an "object" for this purpose.  The entire point is that Glyph of Warding is not portable -- it stops working if it is moved more than 10' from where it was cast, and the intent is that this is a clear limitation, not to be weaseled out of by redefining things.